# Retrieving a task instance scheduled with ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: java, concurrency, lucene, scheduled-tasks, try-catch-finally

I got a `ScheduledExecutorService` for task scheduling in a JEE environment. Some of those task are leaving resources opened when they are interrupted with `ScheduledExecutorService.shutdownNow()` (e.g. open files with a third-party lib like Lucene).

I know that a thread may not stop his execution by itself: The must used way to stop a thread is cheeking the interrupt flag and stopping the method execution, and if the thread is block (e.g wait(), sleep(), etc) or if doing some IO operation in a interruptible channel the `Thread.interrupt()` will make a `InterruptedException` rise. In both cases, the finally block must be executed.
See: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29.

Obviously, I already tried to release the resources with a very well implemented finally block in the Task class, but in some environments (e.g. CentOS) the finally block is not executed when the thread is interrupted. And then I found this very cool note in the official Java Documentation:

> Note: If the JVM exits while the try or catch code is being executed,
>   then the finally block may not execute. Likewise, if the thread
>   executing the try or catch code is interrupted or killed, the finally
>   block may not execute even though the application as a whole
>   continues.

So, what I need is a reference to all the scheduled task in order to implement some public method in the Task classes that force the release of resources. Can I retrieve those references to the task classes from the `ScheduledExecutorService`? Or do you have some cool idea to resolve my problem in a better way?

**The first solution: Wrap it!**

Create a Wrapper class for the `ScheduledExecutorService` and add a property like this:

```
private IdentityHashMap<ScheduledFuture<?>, Runnable> taskList;
```

With that we can access any Runnable object directly, or by the `ScheduledFuture` related to it. For the instantiation of the wrapper, I can get the `ScheduledExecutorService` from the `Executors.newScheduledThreadPool()` method and pass it to my wrapper.

**Another Solution: Extend it!**

Extend the `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`, add the IdentityHashMap property and overwrite all the method that schedules or cancels jobs to add/remove the reference from the Map.

**The problem with both solutions?**

If the caller of your wrapper or extended class receive a `SchedulerFuture<?>` object, cancel the job with the `SchedulerFuture<?>.cancel()` method is possible, bypassing your "capsule". With the wrapper you can avoid passing the `SchedulerFuture<?>` reference to the caller, but with the extended class you can't (if you create your own methods in the extended class you will get the same result as the wrapper, but in a very confusing way).

**The elegant solution: Your own scheduler!** Thanks to Kaj for pointing it ...

1. Extend the `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` to overwrite the
   `decorateTask()` method
2. Decorate the `Runnable` with one implementation of a
   `ScheduledFuture` interface
3. Implement one custom `cancel()` method that actually
   cancels the thread but also manipulates the `Runnable` object to force
   the resource releasing.

Check my blog [post](http://java.ggarciao.com/2011/08/how-to-release-resources-from.html) for the details and code exemples!!!

Comment: do you suspect the VM to be exiting then? and not running the finally block? If so, why not only exit the VM when all tasks have been cancelled (ie implement await termination on the executor)? It could just be a race condition..?

Comment: This happens when a tomcat application is shutdown, and the Lucene library is a shared resource in the server. So, all the threads of the application are canceled, but the VM still alive and the library still available to others web applications. In other hand, when we shutdown the application we do: `shutdown()`, after `awaitTermination(some minutes)` and then `shutdownNow()`. The problem: A Lucene index rebuild is a very long task (even hours), so if the index rebuild is in execution when `shutdownNow()` is called, the thread is interrupted, but the resources aren't released.

Comment: hmmm, I'd raise that as a bug with lucene! threads should respond properly to interrupt IMO (they should implement a correct interruption policy). You're having to work very hard to work around this it seems...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you scheduling? What does the tasks look like? I find it very hard to believe that the finally block isn't executed. I would guess that it's the tasks that you have scheduled, but that haven't started executing that are leaking resources (since their finally block won't be executed)

Sounds like a really bad VM implementation on the CentOS if it really aren't executing those finally blocks. Haven't heard about that in any other VM implementation.

One option that you can do, instead of referencing all of the scheduled tasks, is to subclass `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` and override the `decorateTask` methods so that they decorate the tasks with your classes, and then intercept the cancel invokation.

Comment: My periodical scheduled task updates a Lucene Index (http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html).

For us the problem with the finally block is incredible, but our diagnostic is pretty good: in our CentOS the finally block is never reached (after thread interruption).

Thanks for the advice about extending the pool executor. I will check how to do that.

Comment: @ggarciao - you're sure the interruption is happening within the finally block?  and you aren't doing anything like Thread.stop()?  normal thread interruption should _always_ hit the finally block.  also, is it possible you are doing something inside the finally block which is sensitive to thread interruption and therefore skipping the rest of the finally block?

Comment: Not really, I'm closing some Lucene readers, writers and directories and also those operations are inside others try-catch blocks.